# Get cookies from AuthorizeAttribute Filter

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

Using ASP.Net Web API 2, is it possible to get cookies from the AuthorizeAttribute filter

```
public class SessionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute
{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
     {
          // I need to read cookie values here
          // filterContext.??getCookies??

     }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

To get the cookies from AuthorizationContext:

```
filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies
```

Example in the method:

```
public class SessionFilter : AuthorizeAttribute

{
     public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext) 
     {
          // I need to read cookie values here
          HttpCookie cookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies.Get("Cookie Name");    
     }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Share my function to implement i18n in AuthorizationContext

```
  public override void OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        string culureName = "en-US";
        HttpCookie cultureCookie = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request.Cookies["lang"];
        if (cultureCookie != null
              && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cultureCookie.Value)
              && cultureCookie.Value != "null")
        {
            if (cultureCookie.Value == "en")
            {
                culureName = "en-US";
            }
            else if (cultureCookie.Value == "cn")
            {
                culureName = "zh-CN";
            }
        }
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culureName);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
        base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
    }
```

Comment: great...its worked correctly...special thanks...